# Openshift environment variables don't exist

Tags: php, apache, openshift

I've added a MySQL cartridge to a install and can see the environment variables when running php through the CLI interface..

> php -r 'echo $_SERVER["OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"];'
>   // 127.2.234.2

However when calling the same variable through the web interface the variable is not set. I've restarted both apache and the entire app through rhc app restart

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434922/apache-on-openshift-undefine-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You have been told not to hard code the IP Address as it will change.
eg https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html

But when you run your script on your website the IP Address is missing.

```
<?php
print(getenv('PHPRC'));
print('<p>');
print(getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
?>
```

You get this. The IP Address is Missing.

```
/var/lib/openshift/xxf1b5b94382ec898b00xxxx/php/configuration/etc/php.ini
```

Instead of

```
/var/lib/openshift/xxf1b5b94382ec898b00xxxx/php/configuration/etc/php.ini
127.5.nnn.nnn
```

This may be because you have **not used Git to push files onto your server**.
You may have been like me (a luddite?) and preferred sftp for my simple website.

**Steps needed - if you are not familiar with git**
Look on your OpenShift website, the Applications tab, Source Code

```
ssh://xxf1b5b94382ec898b00xxxx@xxxx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com/~/git/php.git/
```

This assumes you have git installed locally.
This takes a copy of your OpenShift git repository off the server and puts it on your local machine.

```
git clone ssh://xxf1b5b94382ec898b00xxxx@pappname.rhcloud.com/~/git/php.git/
```

Cloning into 'php'...

```
remote: Counting objects: 19, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 19 (delta 2), reused 19 (delta 2)
Receiving objects: 100% (19/19), 18.17 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

copy a few files into php subfolder it has created on your local machine

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "A change to my application"]
$ git push
```

This will restart your application and mysql.

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 2.80 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping PHP 5.4 cartridge (Apache+mod_php)
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Stopping MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: Stopping PHPMyAdmin cartridge
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 092cd25
remote: Checking .openshift/pear.txt for PEAR dependency...
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is e7791836
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: Starting PHPMyAdmin cartridge
remote: Starting PHP 5.4 cartridge (Apache+mod_php)
remote: Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

Now your environment variable will work correctly.
Yes, sftp is probably quicker.